# Excel VLOOKUP multiple values for each item

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two excel sheets where i need to vlookup using first column : (Name) in my case.
But problem here is each Name has multiple schools in sheet 1 and each Name has multiple sports in Sheet2 and my final sheet should have Name:School:Sport.
I need to vlookup with Name column.

Please review the below example for clear info. Kindly help me with this case.

**Sheet1**
**Name  School**

Sam     Oxford
Sam     Harvard
Lily    Olivet
Gary    Cambridge
Lily    Cambridge
John    Oakridge
Gary    Santa Maria
Tom     May Jones

**Sheet2**
**Name  Sports**

Gary    Football
Sam     hockey
Sam     Archery
Lily    Football
Tom     tennis
Lily    Swimming
Gary    Polo
John    Scuba

I want **final sheet** in this way:
**Name  School      Sports**

Sam     Oxford      hockey
Sam     Harvard     hockey
Sam     Oxford      Archery
Sam     Harvard     Archery
Lily    Olivet      Swimming
Lily    Olivet      Football
Gary    Cambridge   Football
Gary    Cambridge   Polo
Lily    Cambridge   Swimming
Lily    Cambridge   Football
John    Oakridge    Scuba
Gary    Santa Maria Football
Gary    Santa Maria Polo
Tom May Jones       tennis

Comment: suggest you think about combining sports etc ie Gary : Football, Polo in one cell...

Comment: I have given only sample data , my real data contains more than 10+ sports for each Name and again if i combine , i need to reformat it back to each individual row .

Comment: so have all 10 sports in one cell as the data source, then once you have the result parse it into individual cells for output...

Answer (score 0):

A helper column makes it easier if you're ok with using one. Refer to the image below.

I put this array formula in `A1` to get the number of rows in the output (commit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

`=SUM(--(Sheet1!A2:A9=TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A2:A9)))`

I put this as an array formula in `A2:A15` (a column with 14 rows--the number of rows in given by `A1`):

```
=SMALL(IF(Sheet1!A2:A9=TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A2:A9),(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A9)-ROW(Sheet1!A1))*(ROWS(Sheet2!A2:A9)+1)+TRANSPOSE(ROW(Sheet2!A2:A9)-ROW(Sheet2!A1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&Sheet3!A1)))
```

I put this in `B2` (no need to enter it as an array formula) and filled down:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9,INT(A2/(ROWS(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9)+1)))`

I put this in `C2` and filled down:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9,INT(A2/(ROWS(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9)+1)))`

I put this in `D2` and filled down:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9,MOD(A2,ROWS(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9)+1))`

[image]